# Proof of sine integral

Tags: calculus, summation, mellin-transform

How to prove:

> $$\operatorname{Si}(x) =\sum_{k=0}^\infty { \frac { -\sin\left( \frac{\pi k}{2} \right) }{ k\times k! } {(-x)}^k} $$

Here $\operatorname{Si}(x)$ is [Sine Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html).

Actually I wanted to prove the mellin transform of $\operatorname{Si}(x)$. But I couldn't. I used power series for $\sin(a)$ but couldn't proceed from there. Please help.

Comment: This is immediate from the power series for $\sin(t)$; what goes wrong when you try to do it that way? (Maybe the problem is that $\sin(k\pi/2)$ thing in the displayed formula. Note that that equals $0$ for even $k$, while $\sin((2n+1)\pi/2)=(-1)^n$.)

Answer (score 0):

We can write
$$
\operatorname{Si}(x) =\sum_{k=0}^\infty { \frac { -\sin\left( \frac{\pi k}{2} \right) }{ k\times k! } {(-x)}^k} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty { \frac {\phi(k) }{ k! } {(-x)}^k}
$$
then according to the [Ramanujan Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem) the Mellin transform of $\operatorname{Si}(x)$ is given by
$$
\mathcal{M}[\operatorname{Si}(x)] = \Gamma(s)\phi(-s)
$$
so taking care of the signs from the definition of $\phi(k)$ above directly gives
$$
\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}\operatorname{Si}(x)\;dx = -\frac{\Gamma(s)\sin(\frac{\pi s}{2})}{s}
$$